# laravel 3 not working with eaccelerator

Tags: php, laravel, eaccelerator

Laravel gives me Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\LaravelRequest' not found in /home/scanal/laravel/core.php on line 157

When i have eAccelerator enabled.

If i disable it it goes back to functioning normally.

Can i not use eAccelerator with laravel?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out eAccelerator doesnt support anonymous functions, which laravel uses.